# Browser toolbar with ability to prepend domain name to button links based on current page URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I need to find some way to make Toolbar in Browser (Chrome or Firefox) that can dynamically construct its buttons links (bookmarks) based on currently opened web page (with macros support).

I'm working on different servers (sites that have different domain names) but resources on the servers I want to navigate to have the same URLs.

For example,
In browser I have opened page with URL:

```
http: //myServer.com:8080/
```

I want a toolbar with the following button (bookmark): [someTool]

that can be configured in form like:

```
$host_name$:$host_port$/folder/someTool.asp
```

After pressing `[someTool]` button I want to be navigated to:

```
http: //myServer.com:8080/folder/someTool.asp
```

In other words, I want `$host_name$, $host_port$` macros support to be expanded based on currently opened page URL.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. From what i understand you want a toolbar to show you some kind of bookmarks? Can't you do it with bookmarks? If this isn't what you are trying to do, please expand a little on your question and tell if you want to build this extension or if you are trying to find one already out there.

Comment: Yes, I want a Toolbar with bookmarks that has an ability to dynamically form host name part of URLs depending on the current opened page. For example, on the bookmark (button) specified URL in some form $host_name$/some_server_folder/some_server_page.asp and after pressing the button the URL is transformed to: http: //my_current_host.com/some_server_folder/some_server_page.asp

Comment: * I want to find existing Add-on Toolbar with this functionality.

Comment: Ok. I think i understand what you want, but i'm not aware of an existing extension that does that. If you want to build one yourself, that seems like a pretty straightforward thing to accomplish, by adding some fixed content to the current page url.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I hope somebody have already made this kind of tool.

Comment: Might be better to ask on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out there is no need in any plug-ins. To make such kind of button just create bookmark in your favorites with the following JS content:

```
javascript:window.open('/folder/someTool.asp', '_blank');
```

After opening this bookmark when staying on some page of the server (for example, at http://myServer.com:8080/some_page.asp) browser will open new tab with formed link:

```
http://myServer.com:8080/folder/someTool.asp
```

Tested with Google Chrome v. 40.0.2194.2 dev-m (64-bit)